# Storing value of switch case into a variable

Tags: arduino, switch-statement

I want to store the value from switch case to a variable. The following is the part of that Arduino code.

```
switch(i){
         case 0 :Serial.print("Time in UTC (HhMmSs): ");break;
         case 1 :Serial.print("Status (A=OK,V=KO): ");break;
         case 2 :Serial.print("Latitude: ");break;
         case 3 :Serial.print("Direction (N/S): ");break;
         case 4 :Serial.print("Longitude: ");break;
         case 5 :Serial.print("Direction (E/W): ");break;
         case 6 :Serial.print("Velocity in knots: ");break;
         case 7 :Serial.print("Heading in degrees: ");break;
         case 8 :Serial.print("Date UTC (DdMmAa): ");break;
         case 9 :Serial.print("Magnetic degrees: ");break;
         case 10 :Serial.print("(E/W): ");break;
         case 11 :Serial.print("Mode: ");break;
         case 12 :Serial.print("Checksum: ");break;
       }
```

I don't want to print the value of case 0 as it does now, but I want to store the value of case 0 into a variable. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

declare a String variable and use it in the code

```
String myvariable="";    
switch(i){
         case 0 : myvariable="Time in UTC (HhMmSs):";break;
...}
```

---

Update

i think you can use substring and toInt methods to get corresponding values of hours, minutes and seconds

```
    String mytime = "121314";
    String temp = mytime.substring(0,2);//will give you "12"
    int hours = temp.toInt();
    temp = mytime.substring(2,4);//will give you "13"
    int minutes = temp.toInt();
    temp = mytime.substring(4);//will give you "14"
    int seconds = temp.toInt();
```

[link to substring description](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringSubstring)

Comment: I don't want the string "Time in UTC (HhMmSs):", I only want the value of case 0.

Comment: Sory, not clear what do you mean by "value of case 0". Do you want to store "0"? Then change type of myvariable to integer or maybe you need to add a value into the string  "Time in UTC (HhMmSs):" ?

Comment: If I use the code I posted above then case 0 is going to give me the value of UTC

Comment: Sorry, I think i wasn't clear. I want to to switch a statement separated by ','. It is in format - Time, Date, Location. Case 0 means Time which is in integer format. I want to store this value in a variable.

Comment: I suppose the result you want to see in terminal window is something like: "Time in UTC 12:13:14" ?

Comment: No I don't want to display the UTC value in the terminal window. What i want is just to store that value somewhere because I need to modify the UTC value according to different time zones.

Comment: is the **hhmmss** value of string type or byte array or something else? In your code i see you only have a general string without any information of how do you obtain values.